# Type error in implementation of Hill cipher

Tags: python, encryption

```
def encrypt(plaintext, key):
    # Calculate the size of the key matrix
    n = int(len(key) ** 0.5)
    # If the message length is not a multiple of n, pad it with 'X'
    if len(plaintext) % n != 0:
        plaintext += 'X' * (n - len(plaintext) % n)
    # Split the message into n-character blocks and convert each block to a vector of numbers
    blocks = [plaintext[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(plaintext), n)]
    block_vectors = [[ord(char) - 65 for char in block] for block in blocks]
    # Multiply each block vector by the key matrix and take the result mod 26
    ciphertext_vectors = []
    for vector in block_vectors:
        ciphertext_vector = [0] * n
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                ciphertext_vector[i] = (ciphertext_vector[i] + vector[j] * key[i * n + j]) % 26
                ciphertext_vector[i] %= 26
        ciphertext_vectors.append(ciphertext_vector)
    # Convert each ciphertext vector to a block of characters
    ciphertext_blocks = [''.join([chr(num % 65) for num in vector]) for vector in ciphertext_vectors]
    # Join the ciphertext blocks into a single string and return it
    ciphertext = ''.join(ciphertext_blocks)
    return ciphertext
```

When the input is "ACT" and the key is "GYBNQKURP" the output should be "POH".

However, when I run the program, I get the error message `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`.

The line this occurs on is `ciphertext_vector[i] = (ciphertext_vector[i] + vector[j] * key[i * n + j]) % 26`.

Comment: The error indicates that `vector[j]` is a string, not a number. You can't add a string to a number.

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII values like `65`. Use `ord('A')`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, the problem is that `key[i * n + j]` is a string. `vector[j] * key[i * n + j]` makes `vector[j]` copies of the string (e.g. `3 * "x" == "xxx"`)

Comment: @Barmar Do you have any idea what I would need to do to change this? I'm quite new to programming so any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hill cipher, I don't know what you're actually trying to do there. Maybe you just need to convert `key[i+n+j]` to an integer before multiplying.